# Turn Expo Bare into Managed project

Tags: react-native, expo

We started this project as a Bare Expo project because we initially required native functionalities that the Managed workflow did not support.

We've since removed these features and would now like to migrate to the much simpler Bare workflow.

We've removed the `ios` and `android` folders and updated our `app.json` file.
According to the [Expo source code](https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/blob/a222105bb5ef6cb60463635bef7ad1aabd28e5be/packages/config/src/Config.ts#L578) this should do the trick.

However when we attempt to build our project using `expo build`, Expo still thinks we're a Bare project and it throws an error because it can't find `/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`.

We've built the app in the past using Expo, so perhaps our workflow is somewhere registered on the Expo servers? Is there any way to switch to the Managed workflow?

We've tried `expo init`-ing a new project and move over the source code but this did not do the trick.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you manage to sort it out? I also want to move back to managed

Comment: I didn't, no, sorry.

What I did consider at the time was removing the Expo project in expo.io first before removing the ios and android folders and updating the app.json file. You could give that a try.

Also: Expo Bare Projects are much better supported now than back in February so you could just consider sticking to Bare. We're really enjoying using EAS Submit and EAS Build.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late. Just went through this, and if you're using the VSCode add-ons, a lot of the issues I ran into was from how the plug-ins detected managed vs bare. Ultimately, it came down to the fact that in package.json, my dependency for react-native was pointed to a version eg. "^0.63.1" when the expo managed workflow they are pointed to the GIT URL:

> "react-native":
> "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz"

Answer (score 0):

I had similar situation, for me the trick was to revert the scripts in `package.json`. In **Bear workflow** your `npm run android` / `npm run ios` scripts map to `expo run:android` / `expo run:ios` respectively. Change this back to how it is in a fresh project using **Managed workflow**. Like so:

```json
"scripts": {
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
}
```

So both scripts have to call the `expo start` command with the respective platform flag.

Check any other npm script that you might be running whether it was changed when you switched to managed workflow and try to revert it.